Looking to make a HTML widget refresh on my webpage every 30 seconds
I have a script for a "now Playing" feature.  I tried adding the script below as a suggestion to get   just the feed window to refresh it's content:
 <script type="text/javascript">
      setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
      },30000)
    </script>
But it does the whole page and some experimenting didn't work;

    Original script

    <!-- Header Code -->

    <style type="text/css">
    /*CSS declarations for HTML Fragment frag_125*/
    </style><script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    /*Document ready script*/
    });
    /*Head script for HTML Fragment frag_125*/
    </script>
    <!--Header code for HTML Fragment frag_125 -->



    <!-- HTML Fragment frag_125 -->

    <!--Preamble for HTML Fragment frag_125-->
    <div id="frag_125" __AddCode="here" style="position:absolute;left:375px;top:900px;width:313px;height:           101px;/*Add Style*/">
    <div class="spinitron-js-widget" data-action="now-playing-v2" data-station="kchw"></div>
    <script src="//spinitron.com/static/js/widget.js"></script>
    </div>
    <!--Postamble for HTML Fragment frag_125-->
    <!--Body end for HTML Fragment frag_125 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*Body end script for HTML Fragment frag_125*/
    </script>

Searched the internet can't find anything that just refreshes the html/script window content.
Thanks!
